# Max CPU on everything

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, cpu-usage

I just reinstalled windows 7 ultimate 32 bit on my desktop PC, and it seems like every program I try to run maxes one of my CPUs! its ridiculous! Every time I load a web page in any browser it maxes a core until its done loading.  Every time I start any application it maxes a core, when I launch google chrome (because its multi-threaded) it maxes three cores!  This thing is supposed to be my gaming rig, but I definitely can't run any games on it like this!

I've already gotten the latest service packs for windows 7, and my device manager doesn't show any missing drivers for anything. Here are my PC specs:

4X 2.66GHz processor
4.0 GB Memory
NVidia EVGA 660 Graphics Card
1.2 combined TB of HDD (20 GB free on C drive)

Is there anything I can try to diagnose or fix this?

~~~~~~~~Edit CPU-Z~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

Comment: Download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), and make sure Speed-Step is working (it will tell you the real-time CPU frequency).  I remember when I first built my rig, I had changed some BIOS or OS setting that kept my CPU from reaching the maximum frequency.

Comment: K now what am I looking at here?

Comment: I don't see any options for "Speed-Step"

Comment: look at the CPU frequency and make sure it's what you expect under load.  From the picture above, when you hit Print Screen, your CPU is only running at 1.6 GHz (Under Clocks -> Core Speed, it says 1591.91 MHz which is roughly 1600 MHz).  It should go up to around 2.66 GHz under a full load.

Comment: Oh, ok that number bounced around a lot, I went into my power settings just now and set my CPU min power to 100% instead of 5%.  Now the Core Speed is steady at 2653 MHz, i still have the same problems with processor usage.

Comment: make sure you have the latest updates to all your software then, because your hardware appears to be working fine.  Does the issue only occur with certain programs?  If so, it might be the software itself (either out of date, configuration error, or bug).  Remember, most programs *try* to use as much CPU as they can, although extensive busy-wait loops can indeed cause overly high CPU consumption on average.

Comment: I don't get why it is a problem that the CPU is used 100%. It means that the CPU uses its entire potential to make the process (webpage loading, program start, whatever) faster. Are games unplayable?

Comment: Usually I would agree with you Pincopallino, but if my processor uses 100% of its effort to load a web page then I think something is wrong 0_o.  Yeah, games are unplayable.  I have been playing League of Legends lately, and I can't even run its pre-game client without it eating 50% of my CPU power.

Comment: @Breakthrough Its not really on certain software, like I said, its all browsers, most games, hell even the installer for that CPU-Z software maxed one of my cores and tried to time out twice

Comment: Out of curiousity, when's the last time you defragmented your C: drive?

Comment: Well, windows 7 auto-defrags so I'd say around 3:00 AM last night, but I just installed the OS so even if I never defragged before I can't imagine my hard drive would be that fragmented yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well, my new video card was the only thing that changed since the last time it was working fine and in my opinion a graphics card *shouldn't* have anything to do with a processor spiking all of the time.

Against my best knoledge of computer hardware I decided to replace the new video card with my old one just to see if it fixed the problem.  To my suprise it has fixed the problem.  The old video card now performs perfectly and my processors no longer spike on everything as they did with the new video card.

Does this make any sense to anyone? 0_o

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a case of buggy video drivers?

Comment: I'm sure, I tried removing and reinstalling the drivers for that card twice.  Each with different drivers as well, first I tried the one from the included CD, then I tried the one from the manufacturer's website.